# Convergence In $L^{1}$ in the Strong Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, solution-verification, uniform-integrability

I'm trying to prove that if $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is uniformly integrable, then $X_n$  almost surely converging to $X$ implies $X_n$ converges to $X$ in $L^{1}$.

How is this done?

---

Generally speaking:

Let $\{X_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of random variables, in $L^{p}$, $p\geq 1$, which converges to $X\in L^{0}$ in probability. Then, the following statements are equivalent:

1.) The sequence $\{|X_{n}|^{p}\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is uniformly integrable.

2.) $X_{n}\xrightarrow{L^{p}}X$.

Proof: Since there exists a subsequence $\{X_{n_{k}}\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ such that $X_{n_{k}}\xrightarrow{a.s}X$, Fatou's lemma implies that

$$\mathbb E[|X|^{p}]=\mathbb E[\liminf_{k}|X_{n_{k}}|^{p}]\leq\liminf_{k}\mathbb E[|X_{n_{k}}|^{p}]\leq\sup_{X\in\chi}\mathbb E[|X|^p]<\infty,$$

where the last inequality follows from the fact that uniformly integrable families are bounded in $L^{1}$. Now that we know that $X\in L^{p}$, uniform integrability of $\{|X_{n}|^{p}\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ implies that the family $\{|X_{n}-X|^{p}\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is UI. Since $X_{n}\xrightarrow{\mathbb P}X$ if and only if $X_{n}-X\xrightarrow{\mathbb P}0$, we can assume without loss of generality that $X=0$ a.s., and, consequently, we need to show that $\mathbb E[|X_{n}|^{p}]\rightarrow 0$. We fix an $\epsilon>0$, and start by the following estimate:

$$\mathbb E[|X_{n}|^{p}]=\mathbb E[|X_{n}|^{p}1_{\{|X_{n}|^{p}\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}\}}]+\mathbb E[|X_{n}|^{p}1_{\{|X_{n}|^{p}>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\}}]$$

$$\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\mathbb E[|X_{n}|^{p}1_{\{|X_{n}|^{p}>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\}}]$$

By uniform integrability there exists $\rho>0$ such that

$$\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathbb E[|X_{n}|^{p}1_{A}]<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

whenever $\mathbb P(A)\leq \rho$. Convergence in probability now implies that there exists $n_{0}\in\mathbb N$ such that for $n\geq n_{0}$, we have

$$\mathbb P[|X_{n}|^{p}>\frac{\epsilon}{2}]\leq \rho.$$

It follows directly from the estimate that for $n\geq n_{0}$, we have

$$\mathbb E[|X_{n}|^{p}]\leq \epsilon.$$

Comment: Isn't this the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Comment: I added the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, is this what you had in mind? Does this imply the result?

Comment: No, "uniformly integrable" is more general than "dominated".  The theorem in question is a proper generalization of the dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof for  1) implies 2) looks correct.

For the converse, fix a positive $\varepsilon$ and take an integer $n_0$ such that $\mathbb E|X_n-X|^p\lt\varepsilon$ if $n\geqslant n_0$. Then conclude by noticing that a *finite* family of integrable functions is uniformly integrable.